# Deleting row from Arraylist

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does anybody have any help,i am using an Arraylist to store details in a Session. When items are added to shopping cart i want to be able to have some functionality, i am beginning with a Delete button (eventually i would like an Edit button too) so i have tried two ways for the Delete button with neither working for me,
first atttempt:

sc.aspx page

```
    <asp:TemplateField> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>' CommandName="deleterow" Text="Delete" /> 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>'
```

With:

```
'onrowcommand="DeleteRowBtn_Click"'
```

sc.aspx.cs

```
'protected void DeleteRowBtn_Click(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); 
}'
```

second attempt:

sc.aspx

```
'OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"'

 '<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />'
```

sc.aspx.cs

```
'protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList remove = (ArrayList)Session["aList"];
    DataRow dr = remove.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    remove.Rows.Remove(dr);
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    FillShopCart();
}'
```

Comment: Please edit your question: 1. Add the binding code (FillShopCart?). 2. ArrayList don't have the Rows property. 3. Don't use ArrayList but List<T>.

Comment: Why `ArrayList` instead of `List<T>`? Are you using .net 1.x?

Comment: I was only taught Arraylist and never shown List<T>, this is my first ever 'project' using asp so i will have to try find some tutorials on List<T>.For this 'project' i need to use 2.0
My FillShopCart is as follows:
    private void FillShopCart()
    {
        ArrayList aList;
        aList = (ArrayList)Session["aList"];
        GridView1.DataSource = aList;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because an `ArrayList` has no `Rows` property but an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.item) like arrays:

```
ArrayList remove = (ArrayList)Session["aList"];
DataRow dr = remove.Rows[e.RowIndex];
```

So this could work

```
DataRow dr = (DataRow)remove[e.RowIndex];
```

**Sidenote**: you should avoid `ArrayList` (or `HashTable`) if you're using at least .NET 2.0 and use the strong typed collections like `List<T>` or `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for the response. but I still couldnt get this to work, i put in the line and even tried different ways and no joy, i now have ArrayList remove = (ArrayList)Session["aList"]; DataRow dr = (DataRow)remove[e.RowIndex]; remove.Remove(dr); Session["aList"] = remove; GridView1.EditIndex = -1; FillShopCart(); But i get "unable to cast object type of "CustomerOrder" to type of "System.Data.Datarow". CustomerOrder is my class where i retrieve the details for to be displayed

Comment: Then you need to cast it to `CustomerOrder` instead of `DataRow`. I don't know what this class has or can, but apparenetly it's the datasource of your GridView.

Comment: Thanks Tim, ended up with:
        ArrayList remove = (ArrayList)Session["aList"];
        CustomerOrder order = (CustomerOrder)remove[e.RowIndex];
        remove.Remove(order);
        Session["aList"] = remove;
        FillShopCart();
Thanks for your time...